# mysterious <kamran> tag

Tags: php, html

At the top of [this page](http://www.blork.org/streetscene/index.php) there's a `<p>` element that contains a button for Twitter, Facebook, and Stumbleupon. The code that produces these buttons is:

```
<p align="right"><kamran></p>
```

When I run the same app on a local Apache server, these buttons are not produced, I just get

```
<p align="right"><kamran></p>
```

Can someone explain what this `<kamran>` tag is and why it doesn't get converted to a series of buttons when I run the app locally?

The page in question is generated using Pixelpost, a photo-blogging platform written in PHP.

Comment: How do you know that code? I don't see it in my browser. It's neither in the HTML source code, nor in the generated DOM tree.

Comment: Seeing as - as Šime says - there is no trace of the `<kamran>` element in the page's source code, this must be something on the web server's side, maybe some sort of additional filter or post-processor. You will need to add more info about the server-side environment - what web server is used? What language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kamran is a pixelpost add-on. The code in the page activates the kamran.php file, which inserts the "share" links.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see in the relevant paragraph when I click 'View Source' in my browser:

`<p align="right"><a target='_blank' href='http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blork.org%2Fstreetscene%2Findex.php%3Fshowimage%3D12&amp;t=Street+Scene+by+Blork-Street+Scenes+from+Montreal+and+Beyond%3A+Hommage+%C3%A0+F%C3%A9lix+%282%29'><img src='http://www.kamran.ir/icon/icon-facebook.png' alt='facebook icon' title='Facebook'/></a> <a target='_blank' href='http://twitter.com/home?status=Street+Scene+by+Blork-Street+Scenes+from+Montreal+and+Beyond%3A+Hommage+%C3%A0+F%C3%A9lix+%282%29 http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blork.org%2Fstreetscene%2Findex.php%3Fshowimage%3D12'><img src='http://www.kamran.ir/icon/icon-twitter.png' alt='twitter icon' title='Twitter' /></a>  <a target='_blank' href='http://www.stumbleupon.com/refer.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blork.org%2Fstreetscene%2Findex.php%3Fshowimage%3D12'><img src='http://www.kamran.ir/icon/icon-stumbleUpon.png' alt='stumbleUpon icon' title='stumbleUpon' /></a>   </p>`

You can see the URLs of the button icons in there. (They are from an Iranian site,  www.kamran.ir.) I am not an html expert; I thought at first that kamran must be a macro defined in templates/egocentric/styles/egocentric.css, but it's not. Is it possible that the site has changed since you last looked at it?